# How to escape single quote (') character in scilab?

Tags: symbols, scilab

I want to print the symbol ' (quote)

for example:

disp (' ' ')

and the output that I would like to get is:
'

But, as the ' is the string delimiter, I can't use that way.

Is there a code which I can use instead of the symbol ' ?

thank you

disp (' ' ')

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer. Inside a string, if you write quotes twice (''), Scylab will know that you mean only one quote, '.

So, to display:
'

you have to write
''''